# ElasticSearch parse error about "compressor detection" POSTing to /_bulk

Tags: shell, elasticsearch, search

I am trying to put work on Elastic Search but I have some problem formatting my JSON file and posting it to localhost.

My JSON file has this structure:

```
{"datasetid": "dataset1", "recordid": "01fc9ae28dd02cd94c97fc759cc0fe9a7b640a3b", "fields":{"movie":"Star Wars", "emplacement":"USA", "movie_id":"40"}, "record_timestamp": "2019-02-08T11:51:00+01:00"}, {"datasetid": "dataset1", "recordid":"906117d0d489f38218df8e01cb228c217c050ce2", "fields": {"movie":"James Bond", "emplacement":"USA", "movie_id":"41"}, "record_timestamp":"2019-02-08T11:51:00+01:00"}
```

It has more iterations, but they follow this structure.

From what I have found by searching on the Internet, I made this line of command:

```
<sirene_v3.json jq -c '. | {"index": {"_index": "json", "_type": "json"}}, .'  \
  | curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @-
```

But I got this error and I have no idea what is going wrong in here:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "errors": true,
  "items": [
    {
      "index": {
        "_index": "json",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "_IOQumkBjKtepv9oHnVg",
        "status": 400,
        "error": {
          "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
          "reason": "failed to parse",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "not_x_content_exception",
            "reason": "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas about it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot use the `_bulk` endpoint without also providing a command line, and that's difficult to do with jq. I suggest that instead of posting to `_bulk` you post directly to the right index/type and it will work.

Comment: @Val, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. "Without also providing a command line" -- you mean the initial `{"index": {"_index": "json", "_type": "json"}}` that the OP *is indeed* having `jq` emit before their JSON document?

Comment: @mbel, which specific version of ES? One way to get this error involves ES 1.x-native indexes (which aren't possible anymore in 5.x or later, since it's no longer backwards-compatible with the 1.x index format).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am using the version 6.6.2 so it should not be this.

Comment: @Val I don't think I got your point. You mean i should do the jq command save it in a new file and then do a new command to post?

Comment: @mbel, I believe Val is encouraging you to POST to `/json/json`, not to `/_bulk`, and thus to not use the jq to prepend a routing instruction. I don't personally see why that would change the behavior in question, but... *shrug*.

Comment: Well, I haven't checked exactly what your jq command does, but you should first dump it and make sure it satisfies all constraints mandated by the bulk endpoint (command + doc separated by newline + newline after the last line

Comment: Hmm. Actually, that's... interesting... that you're specifying a `_type` of `json` but that the error message comes back with a `_type` of `string`.

Comment: @Val, ...in jq, a comma separates two documents (thus, with `-c`, two lines of output); hence, the output is first the document `{"index": {"_index": "json", "_type": "json"}}`, and then on another line the input document (since the `.` passing through input is on the right-hand side of a comma). And being a well-behaved UNIX tool, *all* lines jq emits are terminated in newlines.

Comment: Yes, I got the same result when posting to `/json/json`

Comment: I mixed the error in fact. I tried also by putting the `_type' to `string` and this is the error I uploaded. My bad for this one, i will update with the correct error

Comment: @mbel, what mapping definitions are necessary to reproduce this bug? (Does it happen in an ES instance with no mappings or templates defined at all?)

Comment: I didn't define any mapping and templated by myself at this point. I was planning to look at this after this step completed

Comment: BTW, if your input file has more than one line, make sure the problem still reproduces with only one line in the input file if you're going to post it that way here (to comply with the "complete" and "verifiable" parts of the [mcve] definition); if it only triggers the problem with two-or-more lines of input, be sure to have two lines of input in the question.

Comment: My input file does have only one line, so I will leave it that way.

Comment: Ok so the problem is that jq does not want any commas between two JSON objects,  so I need to remove all the commas between my objects. Does anyone have any clues to do that?